# Access row datasource object in Grid column template

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

I'm using Grid compponent (`ejs-grid`) from Syncfusion Angular UI Components (Essential JS 2).

An issue is that I can't access an original object from a datasource for a current row when using a column template. That's why after clicking on the black square in a cell in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5vghr), the output under the grid is:

> Is the same: false

`let-data` variable doesn't hold the original object from the datasource, but rather some copy of it.

**HTML template:**

```
<ejs-grid [dataSource]='data' rowHeight='38' height='200' width="300">
    <e-columns>
        <e-column field='name' headerText='Employee Name' width='200'>
            <ng-template #template let-data>
                <div>
                    <span>{{ data.name }}</span>
                    <span>{{ data.testFunc() }}</span>
                    <span
                        (click)="onClick(data)"
                        class="clickable">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </e-column>
    </e-columns>
</ejs-grid>
<div>Is the same: {{ isTheSame !== undefined ? isTheSame : 'undefined' }}</div>
```

**TypeScript component code:**

```
export class Item {
    public constructor(public readonly name: string) {
    }

    public testFunc(): string {
        return "testFunc " + this.name;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
    providers: [FilterService,VirtualScrollService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public data: ReadonlyArray<any> = [new Item("Name1")];

    public isTheSame: boolean | undefined;

    public onClick(dataItem: any): void {
        this.isTheSame = dataItem === this.data[0];
    }
}
```

1. Is there another variable except `let-data` we could bind a column template to to get the original row data? If not, what is a workaround?
2. Could anybody point me to docs\Gitub source containing a list of all variables available for a column template? I know at least one more except `let-data`: `let-clientData`.

Answer (score 0):

By default,  column template rendering provides additional details(like column object, index, etc) along with the row data. This detail is used to customize the template column based on user scenarios. So while comparing this object with `data[0]`, its always failed.

Comment: Thank you. I know _why_ the comparison to `data[0]` fails. This is the exact issue here. However, the question is how to get access to the **original** item from the datasource and not to some kind of an object from the datasource item internally cloned by Grid and provided via `let-data`?

Comment: Also, if you're working with Syncfusion, please note that it in your answers. I guess its the StackOverflow \ StackExchange policy rule.